# How do I select the uploaded image in ckeditor?

Tags: coldfusion, ckeditor

How do I get the uploaded image to show in the small display area?  Also, why doesn't the URL automatically populate in the Image Info tab?  Do I need to set something else?  The browser shows the listing in the directory, but it doesn't allow clicking and adding to the url.  Where is clear documentation on how to do this with 4.5.11?

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
width: 1200,
height:550,
filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'browseImage.cfm',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'browseImage.cfm?type=Images',
filebrowserUploadUrl : 'uploadImage.cfm',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'uploadImage.cfm?type=Images',
toolbarGroups: [
{"name":"basicstyles","groups":["basicstyles"]},
{"name":"links","groups":["links"]},
{"name":"paragraph","groups":["list","blocks"]},
{"name":"document","groups":["mode"]},
{"name":"insert","groups":["insert"]},
{"name":"styles","groups":["styles"]},
{"name":"about","groups":["about"]}
],
// Remove the redundant buttons from toolbar groups defined above.
removeButtons:   'Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Anchor,Styles,Specialchar'
} );
```

Comment: Do I have to purchase ckfinder to get this feature to work whereas it worked in previous versions?

Comment: What version of CF? Also, it would help to post a small [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue in your environ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to purchase CKFinder for it to work.  Thanks!